# Using JNI to load another JNI library?

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

I need to implement a native method, let's say "public native void someFunc();". I have two libraries, libabc.so and libdef.so. Java uses System.loadLibrary(); to load libabc.so (which does not implement the method), but the JNI implementation is in libdef.so. Currently, I'm doing the following in libabc.so.

```
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL JNI_OnLoad(JavaVM *jvm, void *reserved){
JNIEnv *env;
jclass cls;
jmethodID get_load_id;
jstring name;

jvm->GetEnv((void**)&env, JNI_VERSION_1_4);
cls = env->FindClass("java/lang/System");
get_load_id = env->GetStaticMethodID(cls, "load", "(Ljava/lang/String;)V");
name = env->NewStringUTF("/lib/libdef.so");
env->CallStaticVoidMethod(cls, get_load_id, name);

return JNI_VERSION_1_4;
}
```

However, I'm getting an error (from android logcat) "JNI_OnLoad returned bad version (-1) in /lib/libdef.so" If I load libdef.so directly from Java, I don't get this error. In addition, if I make another native method "loadDef()" and implement it with the same code, it also works. The problem, I think, is using jvm->GetEnv() but I'm not sure. Also, I don't even know if this would allow me to achieve what I want (use one JNI library to load another to implement). The reason I'm doing this is complicated, but there are no alternatives.

Comment: Oh, some more information. On the logcat, before getting the error, I'm seeing "Trying to load lib /lib/libdef.so 0x0" I think it means it's trying to load the library to 0x0. Why is that?

Comment: I'm not sure it's reasonable to expect `loadLibrary()` to be reentrant. The fact that this works from a normal native method seems to bear that suspicion out. Why don't you try us with that complicated reason -- maybe we can help think of an alternative.

Comment: I could try `RegisterNatives`, but that means I have to load the library manually and find where the functions are. If loadLibrary() is not reentrant and that's the problem, I may have to do that.

Comment: You could probably use the native library loading functionality built into the OS. Just do it in the C++ code as you would normally if you needed access to another DLL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I still don't have a solution for the problem of loading another JNI library in JNI_OnLoad, I found the first native function that is called, replaced it, and in that function, I run the loadLibrary code. Then I call the native method again from JNI and it runs the new version of the method.